Divergence calculation inconsistency
In a scenario, where a single point charge is positioned at the origin, if one were to calculate the divergence of the electric field produced by this charge at some point (for example (3,4)), the value we get will be non zero when we use the expression of divergence shown below:
$$\nabla \cdot \vec{F} = \frac{\partial{F_x}}{\partial{x}} + \frac{\partial{F_y}}{\partial{y}}$$
But, it is also accepted that the value of divergence must be zero at all points in the field, except at the location of the charge.
What can be the resolution to this contradiction, or what is the gap in understanding in knowing the difference?

"the value we get will be non zero" The divergence is zero everywhere except the origin. How do you expect us to know what you did wrong if you don't show your work?

@VincentThacker , please check now.

Have you seen the answer to this question https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/281544/

@Peltio , yes that answers my question, thank you so much.

Why doesn’t your divergence have the $\partial F_z/\partial z$ term? The field of a point charge is three dimensional.

@KiranChannayanamath  I am seconding Ghoster's comment. In the first version of your question you had the correct three-dimensional expression $\vec{\nabla} \cdot \vec{F}=\partial F_x /\partial x+\partial F_y / \partial y+\partial F_z / \partial z$. In the present version of your question you have suddenly omitted the $F_z$ term. Are you referring to the 3-dimensional or the 2-dimensional case? A point charge is normally living in three space dimensions. You should clarify this.

Note also that in the 3-dimensional case, the vector field $\vec{F}(\vec{x}) = \vec{x}/|\vec{x}|^3$  (Coulomb field) satisfies $\vec{\nabla} \cdot \vec{F}(\vec{x})=4\pi \delta^{(3)}(\vec{x})$ (see my answer), whereas in the 2-dimensional case it is the vector field $\vec{F}(\vec{x})= \vec{x}/|\vec{x}|^2$ which satisfies $\vec{\nabla} \cdot \vec{F}(\vec{x})= 2 \pi \delta^{(2)}(\vec{x})$.

the value we get will be non zero when we use the expression of divergence shown below Yes, you’ll get the wrong answer if you use the wrong formula.

$$\vec{\nabla} \cdot \frac{\vec{x}}{| \vec{x} |^3} = 4 \pi \delta^{(3)}(\vec{x})$$
